# How to to fit the tables shown in the code in my webpage both mobile and pc

Tags: html

I Just found the solution after a bit search and this question answered.

You just need to include in every .php page the follow tag after header.

For example in index.php page just try to look for this:

```
<html>
<head>
blab bla bla bla bla 
</head>
```

And under the  < head > thing just put this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.4">
```

Just edit the initial scale to minimum possible and the view of your webpage will fit almost on every android/ios device.

Comment: can you please add a working snippet?

Comment: you can use vw (viewport width) or vh (viewport height) units to define the width and height. This will mak sure it doesn't overflow. Or you simply just use media queries.

Comment: thanks for that i just searched and posted the fix in detail.